# R-Convert character array of unequal length to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to `R`, would be really grateful if anybody can help me with this issue. I am trying to convert `char` list to a data frame in `R`.

The `char` list looks like this.

```
 chr [1:6]   
 [1] "Colour: Gold|Style: Without Offers"                     
 [2] "Colour: Gold|Style: Without Offers|Verified Purchase" .  
 [3] "Colour: Gold|Style: With Offers|Verified Purchase"   
 [4] "Colour: Gold|Style: Without Offers|Verified Purchase"  
 [5] "Colour: Black|Verified Purchase" .   
 [6] "Colour: Gold|Style: Without Offers" .
```

The desired output looks like this:

```
Colour Style PurchaseType
========================

[1]  Gold  Without Offers     NA .   
[2]  Gold  Without Offers   Verified Purchase .   
[3]  Gold  With Offers      Verified Purchase .   
[4]  Gold  Without Offers   Verified Purchase     
[5]  Black  NA .            Verified Purchase .  
[6]  Gold  Without Offers"   NA
```

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Please post the output of `dput(chr[1:6])` as to make your example copy-paste'able

Comment: c("Colour: Gold|Style: Without Offers", "Colour: Gold|Style: Without Offers|Verified Purchase", 
"Colour: Gold|Style: Without Offers|Verified Purchase", "Colour: Gold|Style: Without Offers|Verified Purchase", 
"Colour: Black|Style: Without Offers|Verified Purchase", "Colour: Gold|Style: Without Offers", 
"Colour: Gold|Style: With Offers", "Colour: Gold|Style: Without Offers", 
"Colour: Gold|Style: Without Offers", "Colour: Black|Style: Without Offers|Verified Purchase"
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could split the string by the delimiter and `rbind` after rearrange the input fields.

```
lst <- lapply(strsplit(v1, "\\||\\w+\\:\\s*", perl = TRUE), function(x) {
                x1 <- x[nzchar(x)]
                if(length(grep("Offer", x1))==0) c(x1[1], NA, x1[2]) else x1})

d1 <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, `length<-`,
              max(lengths(lst)))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(d1) <- c("Colour", "Style", "PurchaseType")
d1
#   Colour          Style      PurchaseType
#1   Gold Without Offers              <NA>
#2   Gold Without Offers Verified Purchase
#3   Gold    With Offers Verified Purchase
#4   Gold Without Offers Verified Purchase
#5  Black           <NA> Verified Purchase
#6   Gold Without Offers              <NA>
```